How to go about building a spam sniper bot on ethereum
I am interested in sniping[buying] tokens in the very first block in which their trading gets enabled. However, for most tokens I find the transaction to enable trading is sent privately bypassing the public mempool, making it impossible to snipe it in the same block using standard methods.
I came across this brute force way of trying to snipe by sending a buy transaction in each block in a certain interval till the txn succeeds. Though I couldn't find much on the exact details on how its done.
I am interested in the best way to carry out such brute force and would like some pointers.
Specifically:

how can I reliably send a transaction in each block?
what should I set the transaction config as- mainly gas fee? If I put too high a gas fee do I risk frontrunning the enable trading txn itself?
Any other risk/point of failure I need to aware of?


In general, you have the best control over transaction positioning if you send it privately, outside the typical mempool. So using something like Flashbots. Although I'm not sure what kind of functionality such tools support nowadays.
If, for some reason, you want to use public mempool, here are some ideas:

Route tx through your smart contract that makes sure that the tx is forwarded only if the block is the one you want
Similarily, in the same smart contract, you can check whether the trading has started already
No good ideas about how to set the gas fees. Probably by doing some analysis on the previous block(s) and choosing a fee that "should" land you in a desirable spot in the block.
Remember that you are probably not the only one trying to use such tactics

